# Check if timestamp is contained in date

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to check if a datetime is contained in current date, but I'm not veing able to do it.

This is my query:

```
select 
date(timestamp) as event_date,
count(*)
from pixel_logs.full_logs f
where 1=1
where event_date = CUR_DATE()
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: there is no CUR_DATE() function in BigQuery! Use CURRENT_DATE()

Answer (score 4):

Like Mikhail said, you need to use `CURRENT_DATE()`. Also, `count(*)` requires you to `GROUP BY` the date in your example. I do not know how your data is formatted, but one way to modify your query:

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  table AS (
SELECT
  1494977678 AS timestamp_secs) -- Current timestamp (in seconds)

SELECT
  event_date,
  COUNT(*) as count
FROM (
  SELECT
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(timestamp_secs)) AS event_date,
    CURRENT_DATE()
  FROM
    table)
WHERE
  event_date = CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY
  event_date;
```